# utf-16le to UTF-8

Tags: php, macos, file, encoding

I am using `php` on `osx terminal` to open the file generated with `windows`.

I confirmed file is `utf-16le` encoded

`$file --mime myfile.ini`

`myfile.ini: text/plain; charset=utf-16le`

Now I convert it to UTF-8 with this script.

```
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
    $line = rtrim($line);
    $line = mb_convert_encoding($line,"UTF-8","UTF-16LE"); 
    var_dump($line);
}
```

somehow it shows the corruption like this

`string(63) "䘀爀漀洀䐀愀琀攀㴀㈀　㄀㄀⸀　㄀⸀　㄀ഀ਀"`

How can I get the correct encoding???

---

When I don't `use mb_convert_encoding`

```
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
    $line = rtrim($line);
    $line = mb_convert_encoding($line,"UTF-8","UTF-16LE"); 
    var_dump($line);
    if (preg_match('/Optimization/',$line)){print "hit";}
}
```

`var_dump` shows the strange result why 28????

```
string(28) "Optimization=0"
```

and `preg_match` also dosen't hit.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this but in trying to find if `utf-16le` is case sensitive, it could. Can you try using that in uppercase form? UTF-16LE - it's a longshot.

Comment: Thank you, I tried. but it still the same.

Comment: Beware that `rtrim()` is not Unicode-aware and it might corrupt your data any time. Also, `var_dump()` by itself won't show much information here—how do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Probably you may be wrong about the encoding type, use `mb_detect_encoding($line, 'utf-16le', true);` to see what it returns

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't do what the name suggests. I recommend reading the manual page before using it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That's odd. The manual on [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) doesn't mention that (unicode); undocumented?

Comment: Manuals don't normally document what functions do not do. But you can figure out yourself since it doesn't have an `$encoding` argument.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ah sorry, it is just the typo of my article.

Comment: @whitebear Ok. I deleted my comment about the missing `$` for `line`. About *"shows the weird result.

string(28) "Optimization=0"
why 28?"* - Earlier by "weird result", I thought you meant that you saw strange characters. What is "weird" about what you're getting now? What is the file's contents and can you define "weird"? What results were you expecting as opposed to what you're getting now?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I guess `rtrim` might brake the sentence, so I remove it. but still the same

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I updated the article. about the corruption `string(63) "䘀爀漀洀䐀愀琀攀㴀㈀　㄀㄀⸀　㄀⸀　㄀ഀ਀"` and `weird` is not right word, I changed the sentence `var_dump shows the strange result why 28????`

Comment: @whitebear Ok thanks. See the answer below from Álvaro then.

Answer (score 0):

[fgets()](https://php.net/fgets) won't possibly detect line endings reliably if the stream isn't encoded in an ASCII-compatible encoding. Similarly, when [rtrim()](https://php.net/rtrim) seeks for e.g. `\n` (['LINE FEED (LF)' (U+000A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)) it expects a literal `0x0A` but in UTF-16LE the encoding is `0x0A00`. Bad things can happen.

I suggest you read the file in chunks that are a multiple of 4 bytes, so you won't split individual characters, and forget about line endings until you've successfully re-encoded the file:

```
$output = '';
while ($line = fgets($handle, 4 * 4096)) {
    $output .= mb_convert_encoding($line, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE"); 
}
var_dump(bin2hex($output));
```

Ideally, save output to a file so you can use a text editor or hexadecimal editor to inspect the result.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Can you please open the original file in an hexadecimal editor (e.g. [hexed.it](https://hexed.it)) and add to your question the bin dump of the first lines?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this:

```
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
    $line = rtrim($line);
    $line = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($line, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $line);; 
    var_dump($line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I use `UTF-16BE` not `UTF-16LE` , it shows the correct strings.

My problem was solved.

```
 $line = mb_convert_encoding($line,"UTF-8","UTF-16BE");
```

However I don't know why it works,

Even `file` commend says `This file is utf-16le`

```
$file --mime myfile.ini

myfile.ini: text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

Comment: The problem was the wrong encoding as I said in the comment. You were wrong about the encoding format